# MySQL: How to calculate the SUM for an ORDER BY clause based on the results of a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table of donation information:

```
+-------------+------------+--------+
| supporterID | date       | amount |
+-------------+------------+--------+
| 1           | 2018-01-01 | 100    |
| 2           | 2018-01-07 | 10     |
| 3           | 2018-01-09 | 5000   |
| 1           | 2018-02-01 | 100    |
| 2           | 2018-02-03 | 10     |
| 1           | 2018-02-10 | 100    |
| 2           | 2018-03-14 | 10     |
| 3           | 2018-03-18 | 5      |
+-------------+------------+--------+
```

I need to select supporters ordered by the total value of their donations since the 1st of February, then by that `total` value. Ignoring all donations made before February 1st.

My non-executing query is:

```
SELECT supporterID, sum(amount) AS total
FROM donations
WHERE date >= 2018-02-01
GROUP BY supporter_id
ORDER BY total desc
LIMIT 10
```

The problem is that `sum(amount)` is calculated from **all** of the donations, not just on the donations since February 1st. `supporterID 3` is returned as the top result because they made a donation of 5000 in January.

The results should be:

```
+-------------+-------+
| supporterID | total |
+-------------+-------+
| 1           | 200   |
| 2           | 20    |
| 3           | 5     |
+-------------+-------+
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: use quotes around `2018-02-01`. else the comparison is against 2018-2-1=2015.

Comment: ah, thanks, you're right!

Answer (score 1):

As per [Vamsi's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49412676/mysql-how-to-calculate-the-sum-for-an-order-by-clause-based-on-the-results-of-a#comment85827086_49412676), the problem was my lack of quotes, rather than the query itself.

Here's the working query:

```
SELECT supporterID, sum(amount) AS total
FROM donations
WHERE date >= '2018-02-01'
GROUP BY supporter_id
ORDER BY total desc
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: i tried that, but it won't let me because people have commented and edited it